# When I tried to change the port number on web logic server I got the error described

Tags: weblogic12c

When I tried to change the port number from 7001 to 9002, the following error message was produced:

> Console/Management requests or requests with 
>   specified to 'true' can only be made through an administration
>   channel.

I am not able to open it

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your question**

1. Admin port is enabled in your domain.
2. Check in the config.xml file and identify for the admin port
3. By default the admin port is : 9002
   https://hostname:9002/console

Comment: where can i find config.xml

Comment: It will be in this location DOMAIN_NAME/config/config.xml